# flash screen issue with ratchet framework

Tags: css

i am using ratchet framework but it showing black flash screen before starts my application on mobile and it is very annoying

how can i remove that screen or suggest me some other framework

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Notes</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

    <!-- Roboto -->


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/css/ratchet.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/css/ratchet-theme-android.min.css">

    <script src="../../dist/js/ratchet.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <header class="bar bar-nav">
  <a class="icon icon-left-nav pull-left"></a>
  <a class="icon icon-compose pull-right"></a>
  <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
</header>
</body>
```

Comment: can we see your ratchet css??

Comment: i downloaded entire source code from ratchet.com nd using the same for my code.